# How to force cmake not to configurate dependency directories?

Tags: cmake, configuration

I have a camke project as follows:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)
project(study)

## add 3d-party libraries 
add_subdirectory(deps/eigen) 

## self-defined directory
add_subdirectory(tests)
```

where `/tests/` directory is made by myself, but `/deps/eigen` is a 3d-party directory.
Every time I make changes in `/tests/CMakeLists.txt` and run `cmake ..` in `build` directory. cmake reconfigures the 3d-party directory, i.e., rerunning `deps/eigen/CMakeLists.txt` again even though I did not change it. This is time-consuming. Is there a way to force cmake not to reconfigure 3d-party dependency directories if nothing is changed about it?

Comment: When you change any `CMakeLists.txt` in your project, CMake cannot be sure whether given change affects on other `CMakeLists.txt` or not. E.g. your `tests/CMakeLists.txt` could set some properties for Eigen target, so creation of this target in `deps/eigen/CMakeLists.txt` could be changed. As far as I know, CMake doesn't cache parse results for separate `CMakeLists.txt`

Comment: @Tsyvarev Thanks. Is there any way to force ```cmake``` not to reconfigure some 3d-party directories involved through ```add_subdirecory``` command? Because I am sure I will not change ```Eigen``` target.

Comment: Not sure what do you mean by "reconfiguring *directories*": CMake (re)configures a **whole project** by reading **all** `CMakeLists.txt`'s (and other included CMake files) for that project. Probably, you want CMake to not re-*read* content of some `CMakeLists.txt`, and you think that avoiding such reading could reduce configuration time. But again, CMake does not cache results of parsing of a single `CMakeLists.txt`, so when need to configure the project, CMake has no other way than reading all `CMakeLists.txt`'s again.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Thank you. You are right. I would like CMake to not re-read the content of some ```CMakeLists.txt``` in some subdirectories. But as you said, CMake probably does not give us this possibility for that.

Comment: Not familiar with eigen, but it may be possible to set this up as a seperate project and importing it as imported lib. You could basically execute `cmake --build eigen_binary_dir` during each configuration which should complete reasonably fast, since nothing about the eigen project changes (I assume).